# What am I not getting about [DateTime]::ParseExact()?

Tags: powershell, datetime, exception, format

```
$timeinfo = "01-‎06‎-2017 ‏‎12:34"
$template = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
[DateTime]::ParseExact($timeinfo, $template, $null)
```

results in:

```
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized
as a valid DateTime."
At line:3 char:1
+ [DateTime]::ParseExact($timeinfo, $template, $null)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

I can't tell what is wrong here? Why is my string not a valid datetime when I specify in the template how it should read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some strange characters in your `$timeinfo` variable. When copying and pasting, I am getting this:

[image: Strange characters]

You can see this by pressing the right or left arrow and going through the string; it pauses at the odd character.

Changing to `$timeinfo = "01-06-2017 12:34"`, your code works as expected. Copy and paste this string to test.

**Edit** - Using a [Unicode converter](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter), it looks like this is [LRM control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark)

Comment: @user3272783 No problem - this has caught me out in Certificate thumbprints before. Added more info to answer if you are interested. Consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)/[upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the answer if you found in it helpful!

Comment: How do you remove these strange characters from the string using a function within the script though?

Answer (score 1):

You probably copy and paste the code because there are incorrect characters in the `$timedate`, try copy and paste this:

```
$timeinfo = "01-06-2017 12:34"
$template = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
[DateTime]::ParseExact($timeinfo, $template, $null)
```