# String to time conversion works, tring variable to time conversion doesn't

Tags: powershell, date, datetime

I am trying to do some Powershell scripting with dates coming from file metadata. When I access the metadata, the date I want is returned as a string, not as a date, and so I need to convert it. I'm new to powershell, so my issue is probably a syntax issue.

When I try to do the conversion by manually copying the string value into the function, it works as expected:

```
> [DateTime]::ParseExact('2019- 04- 26   1:58 PM', 'yyyy- MM- dd   h:mm tt', $null)

Friday, April 26, 2019 1:58:00 PM
```

But when I try to do the conversion using the string variable, it doesn't:

```
> $test."Date taken"
‎2019- ‎04- ‎26 ‏‎1:58 PM
> [DateTime]::ParseExact($test."Date taken", 'yyyy- MM- dd   h:mm tt', $null)
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:1
+ [DateTime]::ParseExact($test."Date taken", 'yyyy- MM- dd   h:mm tt' ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

Why doesn't this work?

I already tried using trim() as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784919/parseexact-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime)

And I also tried using .replace(' ','') and the date format string 'yyyy-MM-ddh:mmtt', and as before it works when I put the literal string in, but not the variable string.

Edit 1:
I continued looking around on stackoverflow and messing around, and it looks like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185145/what-am-i-not-getting-about-datetimeparseexact?rq=1) is what is happening, but on that post they only say to copy and paste. How do I eliminate these strange characters from the string using a function?

Edit 2:
I was able to eliminate the weird characters using

```
$test."Date taken" -replace '[^ ampAMP0-9:-]'
```

I found that the exact ordering of the regex pattern is very important.

Although I did figure this out, I think I should leave this so that other poor souls that have this problem can see how exactly I fixed it.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Code used     `$test = @{}`
    `$test."Date taken" = '2019- 04- 26   1:58 PM'`
    `[DateTime]::ParseExact($test."Date taken", 'yyyy- MM- dd   h:mm tt', $null)`

Comment: Show us how you populate `$test."Date taken"` My guess is your variable has the date plus an extra line, maybe blank.  See if running `test."Date taken" -split '\n' | measure` shows a count of 2.

Comment: Like I said, the characters are Left To Right Control Characters as in one of the linked posts. I've figured out that I need to use a regex to filter these, took me quite a while to get it to work right but it's fixed. Unsure if I should delete this question or leave it in case someone else comes across this weird issue.

Comment: Also for future reference, I populated this using the Get-FileMetaData function provided by this module: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-FileMetaData-3a7ddea7

Comment: I think you should just close it as a duplicate to the question/answer you refering to: ? [What am I not getting about \[DateTime\]::ParseExact()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185145/what-am-i-not-getting-about-datetimeparseexact)

Comment: Your input string is littered with LTR/RTL 0-width chars, `$_."Date taken" -replace '\p{Cf}'` will take care of removing them